# Solve for Hyperbola a or b value based on area

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I have a hyperbola defined by: 
$$ x = \pm \frac{a}{b} \cdot \sqrt{y^2 + b^2}$$

Where:

- a - is the distance from the origin to the vertex of the right branch
- b - is the vertical distance from the origin which helps define the asymptotes

It is aligned on the x-axis, opens to the east and is centered about the origin.

I can find the area between the y-axis and the curve with:

$$\frac{a}{b} \cdot \int  \sqrt{y^2 + b^2} \mathrm{d} y = \frac{a^2}{b} \cdot \left( \frac{b \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{b} \right) +  y \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{b^2} + 1}}{2} \right) + C$$

I am really interested in the area between the curve and the vertical line $x=k$. So I can subtract this integral to find the area:

$$ \int k \mathrm{d} y $$

Combining the two:

$$\frac{a}{b} \cdot \int  \sqrt{y^2 + b^2} - k \; \mathrm{d} y = \frac{a^2}{b} \cdot \left( \frac{b \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{b} \right) +  y \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{b^2} + 1}}{2} \right) -ky + C$$

These are definite integrals going from some $y_{lower}$ to some $y_{upper}$ defined by:

$$ y = \pm \frac{b}{a} \cdot \sqrt{k^2 -a^2}$$

This seems to work well and the area that is calculated seems to match up well with the plots I have done. If there is an easier way or I did something wrong, please let me know.

What I want to do is, given a particular area $A$, to hold either $a$ constant and solve for $b$ Or hold $b$ constant and solve for $a$.

If I hold $b$ constant I get the following equation:
$$a = \sqrt{ \frac{2 b \left( A + ky \right)}{b \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{b} \right) +  y \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{b^2} + 1}} }$$

Where $A$ is the area that I am interested in. I believe I would have to use $y_{lower}$ to some $y_{upper}$ to get the complete area as per the definite integral.

First, is this a valid approach? If it is, how do I solve for $b$ if I hold $a$ constant? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your procedure is correct! Areas can be added and subtracted. Only be careful when your boundary lines intersect!
With respect  to the other question the equation for $a$ as a function of $b$ is explicit, while on the contrary it has an implicit description and this must be numerically done.

Comment: What is more, if you want simply the plot of curve for $b$ as a function of $a$, try to obtain the vector of solutions for $a$ for each $b$, and invert the axis to get $b$ as a function of $a$.

Comment: @HBR - Thank you for the comment. I will investigate a numerical solution to solving for a or b.